# How can I find a Ubuntu package to use with Amazon EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, security, system-installation, amazon-ec2

I'm looking to set up a new server on Amazon's EC2 and I wanted to use Ubuntu 11.04 is it is fairly new but not too new. I previously used 10.10 which I think is also very stable and time-tested.

My problem is that when I run `ec2-describe-images -o amazon` (get images owned by amazon) none of these are Ubuntu. If I run `ec2-describe-images -a` (get all images) there are about 12k images.

**Questions**

1. Is there a reason Amazon doesn't have ubuntu images available?
2. If you were running ubuntu on a production system, would you choose 11.04? If not, what version would you choose and why?
3. How do I select a good ubuntu image from the list? With 12k images how do you vet them? Is a particular one endorsed or created by Ubuntu?

Comment: For #2, I'd go with the latest Long Term Support (LTS) version - that is 10.04. The reason is that companies that create software for Ubuntu provide support for the LTS release at a higher priority than other releases, and Canonical has committed to resolving bugs in the LTS release for a longer duration.

Comment: That's helpful. Where is the latest LTS version documented?

Comment: LTS versions are released every two years. The Ubuntu Wiki has a helpful page on this at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS.

Comment: also see - http://askubuntu.com/questions/53582/how-do-i-know-what-ubuntu-ami-to-launch-on-ec2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Ubuntu's Wiki

As @Hippo mentioned you can look at the [LTS page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) which has this chart:

[LTS 1.png http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/5526/lts1.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/5526/lts1.png)

#### Wikipedia Page

Also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) has a nice chart:

[Picture-75 1.png http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/4739/picture751.png](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/4739/picture751.png)

#### Ubuntu EC2 List

Finally, Ubuntu provides a directory of their EC2 images:

http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/

And a list of official Ubuntu AMI images:

http://cloud.ubuntu.com/ami/